# Missing Characters when printing

Tags: wpf, printing

We have a WPF application that allows to make impressions.
For many of our customers, and completely randomly, when printing (and even when selecting the printer) characters are missing.

The image below will be more explicit.

[image: Issue when selecting printer]

We never managed to reproduce the bug on our machines.
Do you have any leads?